# Sign In With Apple JS returns 'invalid_request: Invalid redirect_uri.'

Tags: javascript, sign-in-with-apple

I've started integrating Sign In With Apple to my website, but I'm having some issues. I THINK I've configured Sign In With Apple on their end as it should be.

[image: Developer]

[image: Developer 2]

[image: Code]

Next, I configured my HTML/CSS/JS as I saw on an article. When I click the "Sign In With Apple" button, it takes me to this screen:

[image]

I've been struggling with this for hours, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Jackson

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem. A few things tripped me up:

1. In Apple Dev portal, your "Return URLs" need to have "https://", e.g. https://myawesomepwa.com. Meanwhile, the "domains and subdomains" ***cannot*** have https; it must be the bare domain, e.g. myawesomepwa.com.
2. Make sure all the URLs you specify don't have a trailing slash.
3. In your JS code, make sure your redirect URL doesn't have a trailing slash:

Example JS code:

```
AppleID.auth.init({
    clientId : this.clientId,
    scope : "email",
    redirectURI : "https://myawesomepwa.com",
    state : "initial",
    usePopup : true
});
```

Once I did that, Sign in With Apple started working.

Comment: Thank you for that response. I followed the AWS documentation for Apple Sign in and didn't catch that "Under Web Domain, type your user pool domain. Under Return URLs, type your user pool domain and include the /oauth2/idpresponse endpoint. " means that the Return URL needs the "https://". Great, that solved it. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In my case the error message 'invalid_request: Invalid redirect_uri.' was badly misleading! The problem was that I did not create a Key in "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles/Keys".

So: Click + to create a new Key -> Enter a name and check Sign in with Apple -> Click configure button next to the checkbox -> select your Primary App ID.

I followed this tutorial: [Sign In with Apple: Learn About the New Identity Provider](https://auth0.com/blog/what-is-sign-in-with-apple-a-new-identity-provider/)

Answer (score 3):

I have configured the login with apple using firebase and I have also received this same error but we have not add any redirect url in our code.

1. Just you need to goto the identifiers https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers
2. From the dropdown select the Services IDs
3. Select the appropriate Identifier

[image]

1. Add the website url that have seen on the firebase account

[image]

Answer (score 2):

App IDs are not the same as service IDs... super frustrating config. apple and their annoying jargon

Comment: is this an answer to the question? a comment on another answer?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have solved it, I think the issue was the trailing slash on the redirect_uri, removing it might solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error because I had some query strings like `?param=dynamic.value`.

The error was gone by removing the query strings.

I was able to pass the dynamic value this way:

```js
state: JSON.stringify({ param: 'dynamic.value' })
```

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr : just try to create a new Service ID from the Apple Console.

I was getting this issue, created a new Service IDs from the Apple Configuration with the right config and got it working.
I remember I made a typo when I first created it and update the endpoint just afterwards. The update wasn't took into account.
Check you current URL setup with the service with the "Copy to Clipboard" Button. You will see a typo in your URL for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Please make a new Identifier if there's already existing.

Answer (score 0):

if someone still struggles, like i just did, make sure if you have 2 separate cognito pools for `dev` and `prod`, you include them both in allowed domains and redirect URLs like:

origins:

```
my-fancy-app-dev.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com,my-fancy-app-prod.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com
```

redirect URIs:

```
https://my-fancy-app-dev.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse,https://my-fancy-app-prod.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse
```

and save yourself much time from testing on a wrong env :D

Answer (score 0):

I was adding the App Id as my `client_id` in the apple oauth url. Instead it should be the identifier of the 'Service Id'

[image]