# Login with Apple id returns "invalid_request Invalid web redirect url."

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apple-sign-in, next-auth

I'm trying to integrate Login with Apple id in my NextJS project. For authentication, I chose package `next-auth`. So, in the [documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/apple) for next-auth, it requires the following data:

```
import Providers from `next-auth/providers`
...
providers: [
Providers.Apple({
    clientId: process.env.APPLE_ID,
    clientSecret: { 
    teamId: process.env.APPLE_TEAM_ID,
    privateKey: process.env.APPLE_PRIVATE_KEY,
    keyId: process.env.APPLE_KEY_ID,
    }
})
]
...
```

I used this [link](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple) to create the credentials for my account.

For the `clientId` I used an identifier for my ServicesID, right now it looks like `com.test.client`. For the `teamId` I used a string that was in the right top corner. For the `privateKey` I used the key that I generated in my account and downloaded it. I removed the parts where it says -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END PRIVATE KEY----- and made sure the key stays in one line. `keyId` I got from my account.

I store all the values in the .env variable. I double-checked and the problem is not with the .env variable.

When I try to log in with Apple id It redirects me to this error page:

[image: The page that I get redirected to when I try to log in]

Here's the list of my URLs from the ServicesID page:

Domains and Subdomains:

test.com

[www.test.com](http://www.test.com)

Return URLs

https://test.com

I guess the problem is with my redirect url, but I don't understand what is it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sign In With Apple JS returns 'invalid\_request: Invalid redirect\_uri.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071848/sign-in-with-apple-js-returns-invalid-request-invalid-redirect-uri)