# Debugging Sign with Apple (Invalid web redirect url)

Tags: oauth-2.0, apple-id

I'm implementing "Sign in with Apple ID" feature in Node.js application, using `@hapi/bell` library.

Unfortunately, my attempts resulted in being redirected to following webpage:

[image: invalid_request Invalid web redirect url.]

There is almost certainly configuration mismatch somewhere, but Apple decided to show no information what is difference between actual value and expected value.

I managed to find actual cause (`redirect_url` being set to `http://example.com` instead of `https://example.com`), but is there any Apple-specific way to debug it better?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sign In With Apple JS returns 'invalid\_request: Invalid redirect\_uri.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071848/sign-in-with-apple-js-returns-invalid-request-invalid-redirect-uri)